# Login to Docker Hub by command line

Tags: docker

I have read some Docker tutorials and I see this command line:

```
docker login -u LOGIN -p PASSWORD
```

But the registry server URL is never set.
How does the `docker` command know the registry URL? What is the URL for Docker Hub Registry? I have tried this:

```
docker login -u LOGIN -p PASSWORD cloud.docker.com
```

but it does not work.

Comment: See also the documentation page [docker login: login to a registry](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

If you want to login to the default Docker Hub repository, simply use:

```
docker login
```

or more specifically:

```
docker login registry-1.docker.io
```

Comment: docker.io is the same than hub.docker.com ?

Comment: The same. By the way, can update the question by output of `docker info` command?

Comment: denied: requested access to the resource is denied
docker hub just hates me. 3 hours of googling and stackoverflowing and trying and trying: access denied.  - After all, I would not need but private repo for testing. Will try that next.

Comment: as simple as : you need to be sudo. - so it was not docker hub not liking me ;)

Comment: @ArgusDuong comment deserves to be part of the answer. Because the command "docker info" reveals the exact URL of where your docker registry is hosted. 

Namely 3 pieces of info that would be useful for the "docker login" , "docker pull" & "docker push" 
HTTP Proxy: *****
HTTPS Proxy: ****
Registry: https://index.docke*****

Answer (score 21):

You can also login using a Docker Hub Access Token: https://docs.docker.com/docker-hub/access-tokens.

To do that:

1. Access your Docker Hub account.
2. Click on your avatar (on the page top right side).
3. Click on `My Account`.
4. Click on `Security` (on the page left side second from the top).
   [image: Create a token dialog]
5. And then click on `New Access Token` button.
6. Give a token description, define the token permissions and click on `Generate`.
7. Copy and save your token.

Then log in with your new token. Type `docker login -u <your-username>` on your terminal and paste your **Access Token** when requested by the password.

```
docker login -u <your-username>
```

Comment: much easier method

Comment: In my case (WSL ubuntu) could not login with login /password. But when created a token and use it as password, logged in.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use a specific registry version, for me this worked.

```
docker login registry-1.docker.io/v1
```

Comment: Thanks for this comment . Was struggling fr 2 days

Answer (score 2):

In my case docker daemon is not running, so I just restarted it and re-executed same command. It worked!!